# Summary of changes for each API level?

Tags: android

As the title says, are there any sources (web pages etc) of summarised changes at each API level?

I have an app which I've put out to a small group of beta testers and I already fell foul of Context.getExternalFilesDir(), which I hadn't noticed was introduced in API Level 8, when a couple of the guys tried it on Android v2.1 devices.

The majority of my code should be pretty generic but it would be useful if I could find a condensed/summarised list/table or similar that I can quickly glance over.

Comment: On a related note, here is a summary of behavior changes per API level: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html  Not quite what you're asking but related and important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android docs provide a diff between each major API revision.  For example, [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/11/changes/changes-summary.html) is the diff between API 10 and 11.  Unfortunately, it looks like it's only sequentially available between revisions (not from 8 to 11).  I can't find the landing page for the diffs, but you can change the API revision in the URL to see other reports.

Comment: Whilst useful as a comprehensive reference, it isn't exactly an 'at a glance' quick reference table. ;-) Thanks anyway, I have bookmarked it though for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

At a glance quick overview: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html (quite well hidden, Google!). Clicking on a particular version will show a more detailed, but still quick overview on what's changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running the app yourself on the lowest version of the platform you are supporting.  Always.  Run it in the emulator.  There is no replacement for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but I have a look at the the API Overviews when a new version is out. It's a good start to see whats important and new. For example:

Android 2.3:
[API Overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#api)

Android 2.2:
[API Overview](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html#api)

I also like to take a glance on the [Platform Highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html#DeveloperApis) when available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the analysis of changes performed with the help of the [JAPI-CC](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) tool: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/android/

[image]