# Is there a table of which bits of the Android API were introduced in which version?

Tags: android, api

I had search on google, but didn't have any luck. Basically I want this as a reference to decided what I can use and which phones the apps will work on.

Comment: Is this something Android javadoc doesn't provide already? I mean there's filter by API level etc available at android.com?

Comment: Yes this info is in the java doc, toward the top right if you are browsing it in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked pretty much the same question here...[Summary of changes for each API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123708/summary-of-changes-for-each-api-level).

Ideally, I was looking for an 'at a glance' table but unfortunately I've yet to find one so the answer is 'No'. Filtering the API docs by level or looking at the changes is about the only thing you can do.

If I ever get the time I might create one myself but it's unlikely to happen anytime soon.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. If you ever do create one and put it online, would you mind updating your question? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a table, but a changelog of each platform. Browse around

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html

On your left you'll have the links to every release with a changelog for each.

Answer (score 0):

When you are browsing the online javadoc at http://developer.android.com/reference you can use the checkbox at the top right of the page to filter by API level. It's really handy when you're developing for an older version of the API.