# Comparing Android versions from a developer's perspective

Tags: android

Where can I find a tabular comparison of the different features available in each Android OS version that are available to the developer.

I have an idea for an app in mind and I'd like to know what the earliest version of Android OS I can set my project against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question [Summary of changes for each API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123708/summary-of-changes-for-each-api-level).

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a tabular resource (at least I haven't found one yet). See the answers to my question giving options for how to approach this.